# Insert row without refreshing ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

### Overview

Formerly in ag-grid version <10.1.0 a row could be added without refreshing the grid in this way:

```
let model: IRowModel = this.gridOptions.api.getModel();
const skipRefresh = true;

model.addItems( [ obj ], skipRefresh );
```

Since ag-grid 10.1.0 the addItems() method is deprecated and has been removed completely. The documentation says to use updateRowData() instead:

```
this.gridOptions.api.updateRowData( { add: [ obj ] } );
```

The problem is that updateRowData() does always refresh the grid. That drags down the performance of our grid extremely.

### Question

How do I add rows without having the grid refreshed automatically in current ag-grid version?

### What I've already tried

Suppressing ag-grid's new change detection by setting suppressChangeDetection=true
That didn't help. Refresh is still done.

Comment: It seems to be no more possible to do this since 10.1.0. I've added an issue here: 

https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2116

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `updateRowData()` does always refresh the grid." This is not true. `api.updateRowData()` does not trigger a full refresh. there must be something else you are doing that is causing this.

Comment: I can't test it any more. Since it is a long time ago and we got no feedback we had to migrate the whole system to the new data model.

Answer (score 0):

Old one, but since I came across it while searching and figuring out the answer, this might help someone

`this.myGrid.api.addItems([myItem])`